# How to track down a killer who can steal DNA using 21st century science?

Tags: technology, xenobiology, crime

Let's say that a youth had been bitten by a radioactive octopus and gained an ability to temporarily splice the host DNA with one or more foreign DNAs. Below is a general breakdown of how this special ability works:

1. Host come into physical contact with another human's cellular structures such as blood, skin (including dead skin cell) or hair. (only applies to same species which is another human)
2. Within the next 2 hours, host DNA quickly splices any foreign DNA whereby only the most dormant new DNA strains will proliferate throughout the body. After which the host will keep the new DNA for the next 2 hours before reverting back to the original.
3. After 4 hours after coming into contact with a foreign cell, the host's DNA is once again reverted back to its original state (the state at the time he is being bit).

Note: for the sake of this question we shall grant a one-time scientific miracle on how the hell any mutation can be reversed and NO, Timmy here as the host cannot slip through any gaps smaller than this body much less a keyhole.
We shall assume NO one beside his conscious is aware of the ability, there is no harmful side effect as a result from using this ability except the urge to commit murder, he frequently travels around giving free haircuts.

**Question**
How do you track down this serial killer turned pro* and bring him to justice given the fact that he would always commit murder after the ability is activated?

His skills is on par with the legendary Jack the ripper... only different his target is everybody!

Comment: Apparently it's the season for [unstoppable bad guy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions)

Comment: None of this makes any sense. But I can guess what you mean. Have you considered that DNA evidence is more important on TV than in reality? Maybe related:  https://xkcd.com/1105/

Comment: @Raditz_35, there was a batch of cases where identical twins were found not guilty because DNA evidence could not tell the difference between them.

Comment: @Separatrix There have been many cases where the evidence wasn't enough to find anyone guilty. The point is catching a serial killer isn't just matching his DNA to some sample. But this isn't the topic here, I just don't think this is such a great super power if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Raditz_35, these were specific cases where someone would have been found guilty, if only the offender hadn't been an identical twin and hence indistinguishable visually and genetically.

Comment: @Separatrix Very interesting indeed. That doesn't mean that identical twins cannot be committed for a crime because they share the same DNA, that just means in one example the DNA test meant nothing (as it does so often)

Comment: The flaw in this rationale is that Timmy Octopusman's DNA will be a composite of his original DNA plus that of whoever he kissed or touched to acquire a copy of their DNA. If his composite DNA is found at several crime scenes, then the section of the composite DNA that is his will identify him as the killer. Particularly, once they detect that he is capable of 'absorbing' the DNA of other people into his. Suspiciously his DNA will be twice the size of the DNA of a normal person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNA is one among the other proofs used in a jury.

Let's say that your subject A (if Spiderman was bitten by a spider, should we call him Octopusman?) is committing a crime (killing subject C) after having just kissed subject B. If you track only DNA on the crime scene, you will of course search for subject B.

Nowadays, with security camera spreading all around, it's becoming harder and harder to not being captured in one of these. Let's say subject A is seen on footage while stabbing subject C. This is a clear evidence.

Furthermore, it can happen that subject A is also hurt in the act of committing the crime, leaving physical evidences on the crime scene (i.e. the footage shows him getting a wound in the right hand while breaking a glass). The DNA on that glass can be only his, and even though he can be restricted and probed, showing that the two DNA's do not match, a smart detective can catch him really quickly.

So let's say he is taken to the police district for some question. The detective act friendly, shakes him hand and then starts questioning him. Collecting his DNA from the room, it is found that only the detective's DNA is found, though he didn't drink from the suspect's glass nor smoked from his cigarette.

And so his ability is discovered...

Comment: Also fingerprints, defensive injuries, footsteps, witnesses... all the stuff from CSI. In fact, DNA is not that frequently used since, contrary to what happens in the TV show, as it's usually contaminated and thus unable to prove anything.

Comment: Additionally, despite what the TV usually shows, DNA testing is not capable of unically identifying an individual. That is, for a single DNA sample, multiple individuals may be matched in a DNA analysis (the rate I usually see is about one individual from several millions that won't match). That is one of the reasons why you have to get all of the other evidence. The usual procedure is to define the most likely suspects and use DNA analysis to pinpoint one of them (if you begin by searching everybody in a country that matches the DNA you will probably get many matches).

Comment: About @Rekesoft contamination comment, it is noteworthy the [Phantom of Heilbron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_of_Heilbronn). DNA profiling led to the search of a  woman with an Eastern European genetic makeup because her DNA appeared in multiple crime scenes through Western Europe. It later was determined that the issue was only that the cotton swabs used to collect the DNA samples were contaminated at the factory that produced them.

Comment: For all that I know, fingerprints are also not capable of unically identifying someone. Specially since fingerprint computer aided recognition software only analyzes a certain amount of key points.

Comment: @Rekesoft True. A fingerprint can match with several people, and I came accross at least one event when someone was convicted solely from his fingerprints matching the sample, while he in fact did nothing.

Comment: @ksjohn that is extremely interesting, could you please link to it?

Comment: That was a long time ago, I don't kept it, all I recall is that it was in the US

Comment: @frodoskywalker This looks promising, though : https://www.livescience.com/9341-real-crime-1-000-errors-fingerprint-matching-year.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best real life paralel can be that of [Andrei Chikatilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Chikatilo) in the Soviet Union.

No, Chikatilo did not have the power to change his DNA, but it seems that the laboratory that analyzed the semen recovered from the victims body did a botched job and determined that the murder had a blood type other than Chikatilo's, and that allowed Chikatilo to be removed from the list of possible suspects.

Yet, finally he was captured by using other, old-fashioned methods, although way later and after he had killed many more people.

Answer (score 0):

What an interesting and unique idea! I bet the best way to track down such a criminal would be to discover the next victim and implant Nanobots into their blood stream that begin to multiply harmlessly and go to the extremities of the body. So when your perp. takes some hair to "out-maneuvre" police, they will actually be preparing a lighthouse / beacon inside their body. Now that's ridiculous but say for example you knew this perp. disliked a politician or someone, you would have a good chance at catching them with the nanobot idea.

Next suggestion would also be an implant, but based on the: "if I let go of this button, the bomb goes off" but instead make it like Agent 47 the movie, where if that one dude's heart stops his entire security brigade comes into the building. Basically death detector, but this one doesn't work so well because your pro Mutant (Mystique 2.0) doesn't need much DNA to work with and could likely get away without the need to kill their next form.

Ultimately without high tech DNA scanners or the balloons in Daemon (Daniel Suarez novel) you're unlikely to get this character, you may need to develop some lame weakness depending on who the main character is and what they're attributes / skills are. If there's trace elements of the original pro Mutant then sure you could probably invent a character similar to a vampire / dog (Wolverine) who can sense or smell such a pro Mutant.

Best of luck with your character development! Sounds awesome, wish I was more creative.